# PHP file stream and viruses

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm designing a website for my university's engineering related program. I've just added file uploads for registered users to host projects files they are working on. These uploads are done using a html form. The form and file data is passed to the server using Ajax which then uploads the file to Amazon web services s3. The file is not stored locally. Links are then provided on the user's page. The user base is small for know but I'm worried with more users there will be a risk of virus uploads. Could infected files uploaded with this method be executed on the server? Also is there an alternate way of accomplishing this or preventing virus uploads?

Comment: Sound like you need a virus scanner. No, as long as you don't intentionally execute the files on the server, your server is safe. Same cannot be said for people who download the files.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for a virus scan I can run on my server. It's an Ubuntu EC2 instance.

Comment: No, I don't. That's why I made it a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: Simple google search tells me that ClamAV is often used: http://www.clamav.net/

Comment: To integrate it with PHP: http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net

Comment: Honestly, since you are using S3,  the biggest concern is NOT the virus, but S3 download bandwidth cost. Did you read the S3 data transfer out pricing term carefully ?

Comment: Thank you for the clam-av info. What part about pricing should I be worried about? I don't think the cost will be more than a few dollars a month and zero while in the free tier.